# Aligning an image/carousel to the bottom of multiple without the use of positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am designing a one page website, so a lot of it's sections stacked on top of each other, as well as a section that has divs stacked next and on top of each other. This section has a container div that contains 5 divs called box, which is in a kind of grid format. In each item of class box, stacked vertically it has a logo, then a title, the paragraph, and finally a carousel. All of this is displayed in the image and code given.

**The problem is the alignment of the carousel slide in the box div is uneven (picture attached to show alignment)**. **I would like to align it to a certain position that will align them in uniform**.

I have tried positioning the container div(parent) as relative and the box div(parent) as absolute with bottom as 0px, but it squashes the carousel. Is there any way I can achieve this without the use of positioning, and if not guidance into a correct way to achieve this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is div box. There are 5 of these snippets almost identical encapsulated in div 'container'. For redundancy I have only added 1 of the box elements.

```css
.box {
  flex: 1 calc(25%);
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="box box1 ">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/" width="30%" height="auto">
  <p>Live Streaming</p>
  <p class="service-content">We do livestreaming evrywhere in gauteng. We are pasionate lorem lorem lorem.</p>



  <div class="img-slide">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Current alignment:

[image: Current alignment]

Result when using positioning:
[image: Result when using positioning]

Comment: I made your code a snippet and replaced your images with placeholder images.  Your code doesn't match your pictures!  Please correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `min-height` values to both `<p>` elements above the `img-slide` class of each box. Play around until you get the number that suits you.

Increasing their minimum height will result in let's say the "Live Streaming" paragraph having the same height as the "Motion Picture Production" paragraph, which in turn means that all of the elements directly below them will start at the same position.

Comment: Thanks it worked, although a bit hardcoded, it is still responsive! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem man, glad I helped!